# Trying to find and print out a row from file

Tags: java

I have a program that does several different things, one of them being this method to find an item in the file and display the attributes of that file (there are 3) in the row.  For some reason, this is only printing out the first three strings in the file, instead of finding and printing the item I search for.

```
public static void findItem() throws FileNotFoundException {
 Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    FileReader reader = new FileReader("read_record.txt");
    Scanner fin = new Scanner(reader);
    System.out.println("Enter the sku of the dvd you wish to find.");
    String dvdSku = kb.next();


    while (fin.hasNext()){
        String nextString = fin.next();
        if (nextString == dvdSku); {
            String skuToFind = nextString;
            String titleToFind = fin.next();
            String lengthToFind = fin.next();
            System.out.printf("%-10s %-15s %10s %n",skuToFind,titleToFind,lengthToFind);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove break statement, it will be able to search through out the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **equals** or **equalsIgnoreCase** for comparing strings.

```
if (nextString.equals(dvdSku)){
```

Also remove the **break** statement that you have unless you want to stop on first match.

Comment: Also the semicolon after the if and before the brackets is an issue.

Comment: Actually it will compile and end the if. Then the stuff inside brackets will get called every time.

Comment: Ugh, stupid me.  It's always a semicolon haha.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3050552 It happens. :)

Comment: Everything works now, thanks everyone.